# SparkR Tidyr with Null Values

Tags: r, tidyr, sparkr

I am trying to use the `gather` function in sparkR. It worked before but then just recently it failed with this error message. Anyone deal with this in the past?

This was the original function used:

```
library(tidyr)
gather(df, new_col_field, new_metric_field, col1:col5, factor_key=TRUE)

Error in .Call("_tidyr_melt_dataframe", data, id_ind, measure_ind, variable_name, : Error in 
.Call("_tidyr_melt_dataframe", data, id_ind, measure_ind, variable_name,  : 
  "_tidyr_melt_dataframe" not resolved from current namespace (tidyr)
```

Comment: Can you try with `pivot_longer`

Comment: weird it worked when I refreshed the cluster in databricks. I'll keep this function in my backlog though, thanks

Comment: @nak5120 see [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html) for an announcement of tidyr on retiring of the gather function. They recommend `pivot_longer`. However, this may not be the reason for your error message.